# How to write a code to notify on XML file changes?

Tags: java, sockets, ip, client-server

I am writing a XML gui editor using java, which edits the xml file and there are programs which would read that xml file and act according the changes immediately. For that purpose, I need to invoke an `<ip-address>:<portnumber>`, I need to send a small amount of textual data `"/n"` too. To be precise I need to alert a particular ip adress that some changes has been made to the xml file, and that it should re-read it, so that the changes can take affect. Now any ideas as to how to go about it?

Comment: What? I have no idea what **exactly** you're asking here. What are you trying to achieve? Could you try to re-phrase your explanation?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you provide a small code example that illustrates what you try to achieve and where the problem is?

Comment: I re-edited it. Actually, on a particular event in my gui editor, I want some links to be alerted that the xml files have been changed and that it should re-read the xml files, so that the changes can take affect immediately.

Comment: so among *some event* in your application you want to send *some data* to *a pre-defined port* is that correct?

Comment: @'Joachim yes. and that data is "/n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to implement a small UDP or TCP/IP based solution. Unless the other system already defines an API telling you *how* to send a notification.

Java based client/server are described on several locations, [here's a SO question that asks for a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017092/general-java-server-client-tutorial). For this question, I suggest you look at the existing API and/or the tutorial, for detailed answers we need more input.

---

You can start with this snippet - but absolutely no guarantee that it actually works in your environment:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);  // replace with real ip/port
Writer out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println();                                   // this sends the '\n'
out.close();
socket.close();
```

You'll have to add some exception handling.

Comment: Yes, I just need to alert that link by sending small piece of data, rest of the things are taken care by that link which I am invoking. I have seen that tutorial, its quite confusing! Is there any small snippet of code which I can implement?!

Comment: @mad_programmer: avoid copy-and-paste programming: in the long run it will turn you into a code-monkey that lacks the skill to maintain the code he "produced". This is **very dangerous** for you and *very annoying* for whoever has to maintain your code afterwards.